# Form Submission Error on Wordpress Innerpage

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, file

I have a form on the inside template of WordPress.

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Template Form Submission
*/

get_header(); ?>
<div class="entry-content">
<div style="width: 1000px;" align="left">
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" name="file_uplaod" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" /><br /><br />
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" /><br /><br />
File <input type="file" name="test_file" id="test_file"/><br /><br />
<input type="submit">
</form>

</div>
```

But the problem is PHP-SELF is not working after form submission and it is going to index.php page. I am unable to use Javascript Redirect as File Upload is here. So can anybody help me to solve it.

Comment: Try to give your `action=""` (blank) and check.

Comment: Rikesh this will work in most browser but some older browser wont work

Comment: `action=""` also caused same problem. I have tried that earlier and when it didn't work then I tried PHP-SELF

Comment: action="" dosnt work with HTML5 and older browsers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
function curPageURL() {
 $pageURL = 'http';
 if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}
 $pageURL .= "://";
 if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 } else {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 }
 return $pageURL;
}
?>
```

then replace

```
 <form enctype="multipart/form-data" name="file_uplaod" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
```

with

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" name="resume_uplaod" action="<?php echo curPageURL(); ?>" method="post">
```

See http://dev.kanngard.net/Permalinks/ID_20050507183447.html

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can just omit the action from the form tag to submit to your current url. If wordpress SEO urls are active then $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] will resolve to index.php.